# Display 3D volume from an array of images in OpenGL

Tags: image, opengl, 3d, sequence, volume

I have a question about displaying a 3D volume made from an array of 2D grayscale images using OpenGL.

To be more precise, I only want to display the central slices of the volume in x, y and z directions.

I have successfully done this just by looping through the volume data at the coordinates I want to show and painting them using GL_POINTS, as shown here (displaying the z direction central slice):

```
for (x=0; x<sizeX; x++){
  for (y=0; y<sizeY; y++){
    color=volume(x,y,0)
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glColor3f(color,color,color);
    glVertex3f(x,y,0);
    glEnd();
  }
}
```

I know the real world dimensions of the voxels in mm so I was thinking of displaying the voxels as cubes with that dimensions instead of GL_POINTS like I'm doing it now. Is this a good way to do this? I have read somewhere that displaying voxels as cubes generally isn't a good idea.

Just to add, the volume consists of around 300 images with dimensions of 400x350px.

Comment: you are going to think it's too complicated and it would be easier to do it yourself. But take a look at VTK (www.vtk.org) before you re-invent volumetric rendering yourself

Comment: This is what actually happened. :) I first found VTK and thought it was too complicated and then went to implement the thing I described above. I'll think of giving it a second try.

Comment: we've all been there, bought the T-shirt and learned the lesson!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is to display slices of dense volumetric data, I don't see the benifit of using either points or voxels. To me the best way to achieve what you are asking for is to use simple planes, that you texture map with your image data. You mention the dimensions of your grid data, if you want to visualize this fact, you could also use boxes instead of planes. Using texture maps should be far more efficient for your purpose compared to glPoint or using boxes to represent each individual voxel.

There are many Tutorials on the web which tell you how to do that (e.g. [NeHe](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/texture_mapping/12038/)).

Comment: Thank you! This looks better than what I was doing. I'll give it a try!

Comment: Not really volumetric though, is it jakob?

Comment: The question was to render slices of volumetric data. Visualization of dense volumetric data is entirely different and cubes or surfaces may be a better option. VTK or some specialised library like [OctoMap](http://octomap.sourceforge.net/) would indeed be better.